# Foundation magellan is not working

Tags: zurb-foundation

I'm trying to get a magellan example to work but without any luck: http://jsbin.com/xiyoye/1/edit?html,js

I basically just copied the example from the docs but the menu isn't sticky. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the official [doc](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/magellan.html), you forgot

`<script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="js/foundation/foundation.magellan.js"></script>`